# Resolve Spring placeholders in property files without maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using Spring Boot application.properties file with the following properties:

```
api.base.url=http://${host}:${port}/api
host=localhost
port=9000
```

When i build my project using Maven, api.base.url is being resolved properly, however sometimes when application.properties is updated and i run my Spring Boot application without running Maven before it, i get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'api.base.url' in value "${api.base.url}"
>       at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:831)

In my code i have an injected value for the url:

```
@Value("${api.base.url}")
private String url;
```

Is there any configuration i am missing to make the properties get resolved by Spring rather than by Maven?

Comment: have you added the propertysource to the class?

Comment: What would this have to do with maven? Only issue could be that if you don't run maven you have an old version of the property file.

Comment: How do you update the properties?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Don't add `@PropertySource` as that will interfere with the default Spring Boot mechanism.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer What do you mean? i Don't use the PropertySource annotation

Comment: @M.Deinum The flow goes like this: run maven install > run application > everything is fine > add new line to the application.properties > run application > exception pops > run maven install > run application > everything is fine

Comment: @Jens I simply edit application.properties file

Comment: Are you sure the property file is even loaded? In many cases, non-existing property files are simply ignored.

Comment: @ThomasRS - Yes it is loaded. The problem disappears if i don't use placeholders inside the .properties file

Comment: What is the location of your 'application.properties', also what version of spring boot you are using?

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary under Resources (visible in classpath). SB version is 1.5.2.RELEASE

Comment: If you aren't running maven the resource isn't copied and thus not available.